# Counting of tagged questions off sometimes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-wiki

Looking at the `algorithm` tag in SO, I noticed that there are 6452 questions reported:

[image]

Yet going to the tag info page, at the same time it found 6455 of them

[image]

Earlier this morning this was true for `Delphi`: 5799 against 5800. This is not the case at the moment.

But it is true right now for `math`: 2751 against 2752. `Math` does not yet have a tag wiki, so it does not depend on this.

There just seem to be different counting algorithms that produce different results at times.

Answer (score 2):

This may happen from time to time. We have lots of caching that may kick at different spots.

At the moment the counts are in-sync for the `algorithm` tag, so this was due to caching.

Answer (score 1):

These numbers are cached, which explain why they're different. However, I'm surprised that they're not relying on the same cache, so it's still a bug.

Comment: the pages may also be cached and regeneated when something inportant changes